# xcopy isn't working in my batch file, and I am not sure why?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

First time poster here! I usually lurk for answers but seeing as I've been getting a headache on this and I really want this done for my boss I wanted to directly ask and see if anyone can spot what is wrong with my script.

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value')do set "dt=%%a"
    set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
    set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

    set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
    set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

    set "new_name=PayCase_%fullstamp%"

    echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
    echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
    echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

    move /-y "E:\RFT workspace folder\PayCase_Project_Playground_logs\PayCase_ScriptLog" "%~dp0\Log Archive\%new_name%"

    xcopy /e "%~dp0\Log Archive\%new_name%" "%~dp0\Log Archive\sendFolder"

    pause

    EXIT
```

This first part of the script just gets today's date and time and sets it to a var called 'new_name' (it's not my code, got it from somewhere, I forget where). The latter part, moves the contents of the folder from one place to another, then it is suppose to copy those contents to another place in the drive.

Can someone help me figure out why my code is not copying the contents to my sendFolder?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does your script display some error message(s) e.g. `Access is denied. 0 dir(s) moved` or alike? Please [edit] your question and add more details (and remove `java` tag, please). BTW, `move` command does not move directory between different _disc drives_ (volumes).

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry it took so long to reply, I was in a meeting that just would not end. But the scripts just started working for no reason now and I didn't change anything, weird huh? Also thanks for heads up for the move command, I fixed that issue by just copying the contents over and deleting the source files.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see is that you are not using all the switches. Try it with switches `/s`. Second and most importantly you are using the `%~dp0` WRONG!

Type this in a txt file and save it as a batch file

```
Echo %~dp0
Pause
```

Run it, you will already find a `\` at the last so for example you would have a path like this `C:\Wherever\bat\is\` at the last there is already an `\`.

You have typed this `"%~dp0\Log Archive\%new_name%"` which would result in  `"C:\Wherever\bat\is\\Log Archive\%new_name%"`.

See that? A slight mistake can get the whole thing wrong. So try adding the /s switch and editing your code like this

`xcopy /s /e "%~dp0Log Archive\%new_name%" "%~dp0Log Archive\sendFolder"`

Please also follow @JosefZ Comment

Regards,

Comment: The `/e` switch implies the `/s` switch in xcopy - including it will not change the command in any way. His problem is that the move command isn't moving the files to begin with

Comment: @foxidrive I was telling him that whether it moves it or not, he won't get it right until he removes that extra \. So whether we solve his problem or not he will still get an error until he fixes that. And I already knew his problem.

Comment: Windows can tolerate \\ in most cases.  Give it a shot.

Comment: @foxidrive Ha! I have found this thing the hard way. Your comment answers your question. We can never know when that `most cases` will be in this case. Lets just not leave it to chance.

Comment: BTW I was just wondering about my rep. I just have two more to go to comment everywhere. Pretty excited

Comment: No offense intended but you've given an answer that says \\ won't work, and that \s is needed.  Neither of those things is true.  Other's will come and vote your answer down for that reason and your rep will drop.

Comment: @foxidrive What do you suppose? I willingly leave it to the experts. Delete my answer?

Comment: Test the move command on your system and see why it fails, then edit your answer.  You can delete your answer for the meantime and undelete it later.

Comment: @foxidrive Ok Windows is tolerable with `//`